# Which classes are loaded by JVM but not a classloader?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I am going through th chapter on Assertions in Core Java Volume 10 by Horstmann and it says:

> Some classes are not loaded by a class loader but directly by the
>   virtual machine. You can use these switches to selectively enable or
>   disable assertions in those classes.

I am confused by this, which classes will get loaded by the JVM and not by a class loader, I thought the bootstrap classloader loaded the initial classes?

Thanks.

Comment: How about the bootstrap classloader itself?  Also, by the time the bootstrap classloader loads, certain other classes need to already be in place, at the very least Class.class, Object.class, but also any other class that it accesses to do its job, so, there you go.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, but I thought the bootstrap classloader was written in a native language and that it was the one that is responsible for loading Class.class and Object.class? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am not really sure, that's why I only wrote a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Ok Mike, thanks for your response.

Comment: It would be great, if you provided some context, e.g. which switches the phrase “these switches” refers to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All Java virtual machines include one class loader that is embedded in the virtual machine. This embedded loader is called the primordial class loader. It is somewhat special because the virtual machine assumes that it has access to a repository of trusted classes which can be run by the VM without verification.

So if we write code like below:

```
Class r = loadClass(String className, boolean resolveIt);
```

it means that class is getting loaded at runtime by classLoader and JVM is responsible to executing the program.

I hope you got it!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Amal, but the book seems to be talking about classes that are loaded by the JVM and not the primordial classloader (which I am referring to as the bootstrap classloader) or extensions classloader or application classloader.

Comment: There is no reason to assume that a JVM doesn’t verify classes loaded via the bootstrap loader. Further, it’s not clear what that “code like below”, which isn’t even valid code, is supposed to illustrate. When you invoke `loadClass` on a `ClassLoader`, it may still return a `Class` actually loaded by the bootstrap loader.

Comment: The variable className contains a string that is understood by the class loader and is used to uniquely identify a class implementation. The variable resolveIt is a flag to tell the class loader that classes referenced by this class name should be resolved (that is, any referenced class should be loaded as well).

Comment: So The primordial class loader implements the default implementation of loadClass(). Thus, this code understands that the class name java.lang.Object is stored in a file with the prefix java/lang/Object.class somewhere in the class path. This code also implements both class path searching and looking into zip files for classes. The really cool thing about the way this is designed is that Java can change its class storage model simply by changing the set of functions that implements the class loader.

Comment: Digging around in the guts of the Java virtual machine, you will discover that the primordial class loader is implemented primarily in the functions FindClassFromClass and ResolveClass.

So when are classes loaded? There are exactly two cases: when the new bytecode is executed (for example, FooClass f = new FooClass();) and when the bytecodes make a static reference to a class (for example, System.out).

Comment: A JVM can decide itself when to load a class, but the latest point is prior to initialization, [which is clearly defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1). It’s funny that your comments have more substance than your answer, but you’re not willing to improve your answer. Note that your code example still is not valid code and the claim that the classes loaded by the primordial class loader are not verified is still unfounded.

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle doc, system classes without class loaders, refers all classes which is located in rt.jar and are loaded by bootstrap class loader. So, you do not access to ClassLoader object of mentioned system classes.

> The bootstrap class loader loads the system classes (typically, from the JAR file rt.jar ). It is an integral part of the virtual machine and is usually implemented in C. There is no ClassLoader object corresponding to the bootstrap class loader. For example,
>
> String.class.getClassLoader()
>
> returns null.

Finally, we should use the -enablesystemassertions/-esa switch to enable assertions in system classes.